# Ssh client.py not working, showing connection error

Tags: ssh, openssh

My config file:

```
Host server
User new_user
HostName 10.0.1.193
Port 55555
LocalForward 3000 10.0.1.193:6000
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server
```

Client.py

```
import xmlrpclib
s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:3000')
print s.pow(2,3)  # Returns 2**3 = 8
print s.add(2,3)  # Returns 5
print s.div(5,2)  # Returns 5//2 = 2

# Print list of available methods
print s.system.listMethods()
```

Server.py

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler

# Restrict to a particular path.
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    rpc_paths = ('/RPC2',)

# Create server
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 6000),
                            requestHandler=RequestHandler)
server.register_introspection_functions()

# Register pow() function; this will use the value of
# pow.__name__ as the name, which is just 'pow'.
server.register_function(pow)

# Register a function under a different name
def adder_function(x,y):
    return x + y
server.register_function(adder_function, 'add')

# Register an instance; all the methods of the instance are
# published as XML-RPC methods (in this case, just 'div').
class MyFuncs:
    def div(self, x, y):
        return x // y

server.register_instance(MyFuncs())

# Run the server's main loop
server.serve_forever()
```

My server.py is running fine, but when I run my client.py, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 4, in <module>
    print s.pow(2,3)  # Returns 2**3 = 8
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 757, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have checked that my ssh if working and I can ssh into remote server with the given configuration i.e.

```
ssh server
```

works find. Can anyone explain what might be going wrong?

Comment: Is the ssh connection open before you run client.py?

Answer (score 0):

Your server runs and perhaps it does not complain, but this does not mean it "runs correctly" or more pointedly it doesn't mean the server is in a working state that the client expects.

The above is somewhat cryptic for a reason: something unknown has gone wrong, and even though you don't know yet what's broken, you want to start testing things you know should work and verify they are in fact working. This is a useful debugging skill even if the error is meaningless to you.

In this case, the client error message is "connection refused", meaning "refused [at the server]".

Try this:
on your "client" PC in a Terminal/DOS window, run:
telnet [your server ip] [your server port]

You should expect the same error - a connection refused. Perhaps the server is not actually opening the port. Or perhaps the server opened the port, but you can not see it remotely on another host due to a firewall on the server.

Also, running both client and server code on the same host can sometime reveal more clues (it should work but if it doesn't then there's maybe more than 1 problem).